# ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin## login name property missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

In Ms Sql Server 2019
In a Full restored server, included database,jobs, user logins and system databases ( I didn´t the migration  )

Watching in logs I receive the error:

> The activated proc '[dbo]. [Sp_syspolicy_events_reader]' running on queue 'msdb.dbo.syspolicy_event_queue' output the following: 'Cannot execute as the main database because the main “## MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin ##” does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. '

Searching, I got information about orphaned user.

Trying apply the possible solution:

```sql
USE [msdb]
GO
 
ALTER USER [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##] WITH LOGIN = [##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##]
GO
```

I received the error, that the user "##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##" does not exist, same with

```
USE [msdb]
GO
 
sys.sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', '##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##'
GO
```

Received the error as invalid parameter.

Looking the user in the msdb and master database, it´s there but in the properties I can see that the login property is missing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASKRz.png)

Comparing with other SqlServer, there should be the login value.

I tried to execute the script showed but just got errors.

I don't have any backup of these system databases, but I have a second server, the pre-migration tests run there, and the msdb and master user still continues with logins.

Comment: Is your `msdb` restored from a different server, by any chance?

Comment: The login has been deleted. You need to get the certificate for this login in order to recreate it, presumably from a backup of `master` DB or from the server you restored from. Otherwise you will have to rebuild the system DBs. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12636/220697

Comment: Thanks Charlie, there is some process for create a new certificate and assign in master as msdb ? i see now, that login is missing in master too.

Comment: Thanks for repply Tom, im watching now, and yes. The server was migrated so the administrator restored the databases from other server.

Comment: Like I said, you need to either get a backup of that certificate, or recreate the system databases. Do you have any backups of `master`? Was `master` also restored at the same time as other databases?